# How to convert UTC time to Time in any other time zone in C#

Tags: c#, time, timezone

I am working in C#.net - .Net fx is 2.0 which doesnot support converting between different time zones. I have wrote a scheduler based on UTC but it is giving errors of 1 hour in the DTS periods for London. I need some solution so that I can gat the correct time in any timezone relative to UTC with correct DST adjustments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is changing to .NET 3.5 absolutely out of the question? It would make your life much, much easier. Otherwise, you're stuck with the plain TimeZone and DaylightSavings classes, as well as having to fetch the known timezones using P/Invoke.

William Stacey has a [blog post with some code to do this](http://staceyw.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!F4A38E96E598161E!931.entry) - but I haven't tried it, so can't vouch for its accuracy. (In my experience he's usually pretty good though :) There are no doubt similar bits of code around if that one doesn't help you.

I believe that the API he's using doesn't have access to historical data, btw. In other words, it will assume that DST *always* kicks in on the first Sunday of October (or whatever the rule is) rather than knowing that the rule has changed over time. TimeZoneInfo in .NET 3.5 supports historical data where the OS does.

Comment: Agree. I've seen old code doing the P/Invoke stuff, and TimeZoneInfo in 3.5 renders it all obsolete.

Comment: Hi Jon, the blog post is not available any more, stupid question, do you know where I might look or point me somewhere that might help me to find that info?